# How slicing a NumPy array affects the output

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing, output, numpy-slicing

Can someone please explain why you get different array shapes when you pull the same data out of an NumPy array, using the following two slightly different slicing techniques?

```
In [1]:import numpy as np
In [2]: grades = np.array([[93, 95],
    ...:                   [84, 100],
    ...:                   [99, 87]])

In [3]: A = grades[:,0]
In [4]: A
Out[4]: array([93, 84, 99])

In[5]: B = grades[:, :1]
In[6]: B
Out[6]: array([[93],
               [84],
               [99]])

In [7]: A.shape
Out[7]: (3,)

In [8]: B.shape
Out[8]: (3,1)
```

Why does Python create a 1-dimensional array when using *grades[0,:]* slicing reference but, creates a 3x1 2-dimensional array when using *grades[:, :1]*??

Thanks

Comment: That is well documented.  Is there something wrong with that?  Consider the list equivalents, `[[1,2],[3,4]][0]` and `[[1,2],[3,4]][:1]`.  Indexing with a scalar reduces the nesting, indexing with a slice does not.  The numpy behavior is consistent with the broader Python behavior.

Comment: When reading indexing docs, such as https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html, pay attention to the differences between indexing with scalars, slices, arrays, lists and tuples.  The details matter.